# what problem do quadratics solve?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, intuition

Areas of Math were developed to deal with problems which couldn't be tackled with preexisting methods. So, for example, 2D geometry was used to solve measuring problems with land, basic algebra for figuring out basic physical quantities, etc.

What physical or intuitive problem is solved by quadratic equations and their graphs?

Comment: Good point. You should refuse to study such things.

Comment: That's not really true. It's certainly not true today and it wasn't true when Euclid axiomatized geometry. I like @WillJagy's answer better, though.

Comment: Thrown/falling objects, for one.

Answer (score 4):

Throw an object from height $h_0$ with upward velocity $v_0$. Its height at time $t$ is given by the quadratic
$$h(t)=-\frac{g}{2}t^2+v_0t+h_0$$
where $g$ is the gravitational constant.

Comment: This is why one way to measure the height of a building with a barometer is to drop the barometer off the top of the building and carefully time the fall.

Comment: @WillJagy Well, assuming you don't have any string to make a pendulum and do it *properly*.

Comment: Sure. Another method is to walk up to someone who knows how tall the building is, and threaten to hit them with the barometer if they don't tell you.

Comment: @WillJagy So violent. The version I've always heard is that you offer to give them the barometer if they tell you how tall the building is.

Comment: I know, it's a dual pair, homology/cohomology, primal/dual problems in linear programming, Justin Bieber/Lady Gaga,...

Answer (score 2):

The Babylonians solved problems, in many cases stated geometrically, essentially using quadratic equations.  For example, the area of a square diminished by the side of the square is (a given number); find the side of the square.  I don't think it's at all clear what were the practical problems (if any) that motivated the discovery of these methods: what we have (on numerous clay tablets) are essentially school exercises for teaching what was already well-developed material.